# Why does softmax perform well on MNIST but poorly on EMNIST letters?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, regression, softmax

I am learning about softmax regression using [Dive into Deep Learning](http://d2l.ai/). I have a very basic question on why softmax performs well on one dataset and poorly on another.

I tried modifying the results from [§4.5 concise implementation of softmax regression](http://d2l.ai/chapter_linear-classification/softmax-regression-concise.html) on the MNIST dataset and got decent performance. (Fig. 1) However, the model did very poorly for the EMNIST letters dataset. (Fig. 2) Here is the data and model that I used:

```
# the model 
class softmaxRegression(d2l.Classifier): 
  def __init__(self,num_outputs,lr):
    super().__init__()
    self.save_hyperparameters()
    self.softmax = nn.Sequential(nn.Flatten(),nn.LazyLinear(num_outputs))

  def forward(self,X):
    return self.softmax(X)

  def loss(self,Y_hat,Y): 
    return functional.cross_entropy(Y_hat,Y)

# data for EMNIST letters

class EMNIST(d2l.DataModule): 
  def __init__(self,batch_size=64,resize=(28, 28)): 
    super().__init__()
    self.save_hyperparameters()
    trans = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(resize),
                                    transforms.ToTensor(),
                                lambda t: torch.transpose(t,1,2)])
    self.train = torchvision.datasets.EMNIST(
                  root=self.root,
                  split = "letters",
                  train = True,
                  transform = trans,
                  download=True)
    self.val   = torchvision.datasets.EMNIST(
                  root=self.root,
                  split = "letters",
                  train = False,
                  transform = trans,
                  download=True)
  
  def get_dataloader(self, train): 
    data = self.train if train else self.val
    return torch.utils.data.DataLoader(data,self.batch_size)
```

Also

```
# data for MNIST

class MNIST(d2l.DataModule): 
  def __init__(self,batch_size=64,resize=(28, 28)): 
    super().__init__()
    self.save_hyperparameters()
    trans = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(resize),
                                    transforms.ToTensor()])
    self.train = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
                  root=self.root,
                  train = True,
                  transform = trans,
                  download=True)
    self.val   = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
                  root=self.root,
                  train = False,
                  transform = trans,
                  download=True)
  
  def get_dataloader(self, train): 
    data = self.train if train else self.val
    return torch.utils.data.DataLoader(data,self.batch_size)
```

**My Question.** Why did this happen? The two datasets look similar enough that the models ought to perform well in both of them.

Fig 1: Softmax for MNIST

[image: Fig 1: Softmax for MNIST]

Fig 2: Softmax for EMNIST Letters

[image: Fig 2: Softmax for EMNIST Letters]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the EMNIST dataset is simply more difficult to classify.

From EMNIST [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.05373v1.pdf):

[image]